# Second Screen display rotated 90 degrees in iOS 8.3 & 8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, ios8.3

My question is less of how to fix the issue and more of why is this happening:

Starting in iOS 8.3, when displaying videos on a second screen (through either AirPlay or Lightning -> HDMI) the screen is rotated by 90º. This isn't a problem on previous versions of iOS or when the app is launched in portrait instead of landscape.

I've created a workaround by checking for iOS version and screen rotation and then rotating the view for the second window. In case anyone else has this problem, here's my solution:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.3f) {
    CGFloat width = (_externalWindow.frame.size.width > _externalWindow.frame.size.height) ? _externalWindow.frame.size.width : _externalWindow.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat height = (_externalWindow.frame.size.width < _externalWindow.frame.size.height) ? _externalWindow.frame.size.width : _externalWindow.frame.size.height;
    CGRect rotatedFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);
    _externalWindow.frame = rotatedFrame;

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft && [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 9.0f) {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2 * 3);
        _externalWindow.transform = transform;
    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight && [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 9.0f) {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        _externalWindow.transform = transform;
    }
}
```

Edit: tested this on iOS 9 and found an interesting problem that's similar to the previous problem. The orientation was displaying correctly but the frame was still rotated so only part of the content was showing. I adjusted my solution to make sure the window frame is always oriented as widescreen.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, I was able to solve this by only allowing portrait on the VC:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Were you having the same issue I was having? And does this ever result in the image being upside down or is `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` always in the same portrait orientation?